# Python: How to Connect to Snowflake Using Apache Beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I see that there's a built-in I/O connector for BigQuery, but a lot of our data is stored in Snowflake. Is there a workaround for connecting to Snowflake? The only thing I can think of doing is to use sqlalchemy to run the query and then dump the output to Cloud Storage Buckets, and then Apache-Beam can get the input data from the files stored in the Bucket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were added Snowflake Python and Java connectors to Beam recently.

Right now (version 2.24) it supports only ReadFromSnowflake operation in `apache_beam.io.external.snowflake`.

In the 2.25 release WriteToSnowflake will also be available in `apache_beam.io.snowflake` module. You can still use the old path, however it will be considered deprecated in this version.

Right now it runs only on Flink Runner but there is an effort to make it available for other runners as well.

Also, it's a cross-language transform so some additional setup can be needed - it's quite well documented in the pydoc here (I'm pasting it below):
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.24.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/external/snowflake.py

```
Snowflake transforms tested against Flink portable runner.
  **Setup**
  Transforms provided in this module are cross-language transforms
  implemented in the Beam Java SDK. During the pipeline construction, Python SDK
  will connect to a Java expansion service to expand these transforms.
  To facilitate this, a small amount of setup is needed before using these
  transforms in a Beam Python pipeline.
  There are several ways to setup cross-language Snowflake transforms.
  * Option 1: use the default expansion service
  * Option 2: specify a custom expansion service
  See below for details regarding each of these options.
  *Option 1: Use the default expansion service*
  This is the recommended and easiest setup option for using Python Snowflake
  transforms.This option requires following pre-requisites
  before running the Beam pipeline.
  * Install Java runtime in the computer from where the pipeline is constructed
    and make sure that 'java' command is available.
  In this option, Python SDK will either download (for released Beam version) or
  build (when running from a Beam Git clone) a expansion service jar and use
  that to expand transforms. Currently Snowflake transforms use the
  'beam-sdks-java-io-expansion-service' jar for this purpose.
  *Option 2: specify a custom expansion service*
  In this option, you startup your own expansion service and provide that as
  a parameter when using the transforms provided in this module.
  This option requires following pre-requisites before running the Beam
  pipeline.
  * Startup your own expansion service.
  * Update your pipeline to provide the expansion service address when
    initiating Snowflake transforms provided in this module.
  Flink Users can use the built-in Expansion Service of the Flink Runner's
  Job Server. If you start Flink's Job Server, the expansion service will be
  started on port 8097. For a different address, please set the
  expansion_service parameter.
  **More information**
  For more information regarding cross-language transforms see:
  - https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/portability/
  For more information specific to Flink runner see:
  - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/
```

Snowflake (as most of the portable IOs) has its own java expansion service which should be downloaded automatically when you don't specify your own custom one. I don't think it should be needed but I'm mentioning it just to be on the safe side. You can download the jar and start it with `java -jar <PATH_TO_JAR> <PORT>` and then pass it to snowflake.ReadFromSnowflake as `expansion_service='localhost:<PORT>'`. Link to 2.24 version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-io-snowflake-expansion-service/2.24.0

Notice that it's still experimental though and feel free to report issues on Beam Jira.

Comment: Great to hear this! Have you been playing/contributing to it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I had my part in the cross-language effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Support here!

There's no direct connector from Snowflake to Cloud Dataflow, but one workaround would be what you've mentioned. First dump the output to Cloud Storage, and then connect Cloud Storage to Cloud Dataflow.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. Would you recommend using a simple python script hosted on Kubernetes Engine + Cloud Scheduler to facilitate this data dump to cloud storage or should I use Pyspark + DataProc?

Answer (score 1):

For future folks looking for a tutorial on how to start with Snowflake and Apache Beam, I can recommend the below tutorial which was made by the creators of the connector.

https://www.polidea.com/blog/snowflake-and-apache-beam-on-google-dataflow/